# the prisoner box problem, simulating the solution

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to write code to simulate the prisoners going to the box labeled with their number, then to the box that the ticket inside send them too and so on.

I'm getting a list index out of range error but not sure if the code is even right anyway

```
total = 0
for s in range(100):
    prisoners = []
    boxes = []
    counter = 0
    winners = 0
    number = 0

    for i in range(1, 101):
        prisoners.append(i)
    #print(prisoners)

    for x in range(1, 101):
        boxes.append(x)
        shuffle(boxes)
    #print(boxes)

    while counter!=99:
        for h in range(1, 51):  
            if prisoners[counter] == boxes[number]: 
                print("winner")
                winners +=1
                counter +=1
                break
            else:      
                number = boxes[number]
                print("loser")
```

Comment: What is the `shuffle()` function you use?

Comment: Your code works fine without the call to `shuffle()`, no errors on my side. But I don't know what your code is supposed to do.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you store boxes numbers as range [1,100], but use them as indices of 100-long array (0-99), so when it runs `number = boxes[number]` it sometimes assigns number to be 100 and causes error.

One way to solve it is make it `number = boxes[number] - 1`.

Another is use 0-99 ranges in logic, but add 1 if you want to print them.